# Problems with ClickOnce deployment (to me, it's so annoying)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment, sql-server-ce

I've just tried ClickOnce for the first time to deploy my SQL Server Compact application. I think this kind of deployment is very unprofessional:

1. The output setup is a folder including 3 objects, one folder named **Application Files**, a **setup.exe** and a **.application** file which I've never seen in a professional product setup package.
2. Plus, clicking **setup.exe** seems to help user install the application so quickly but user has no chance to select what location s/he wants to install the application. It's installed by default at somewhere in the target computer. And even I tried looking for its location after the installation, I couldn't find it.
3. The last, after the installation, there is a folder named "**Microsoft**" in All programs menu, and the installed application shortcut is located in there. I wonder why it is always **Microsoft**? I even tried editing my **Company** info in **Assembly info** through **Project Properties** window. The application shortcut is something strange when I can't find its target executable file in its properties window.

With all the above ClickOnce can bring to me, I consider it as a funny job for testing the application only not for publishing a commercial application.

Could you please correct me if there is any wrong in #1, #2, #3 and please give me a better solution for deployment, I'm interested in SQL server (service-based and file-based) application only?

Your help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A ClickOnce install is a per user "sandboxed" install, not a normal install you think about when installing normal applications. The .application file is used by the server as a manifest and to determine if it needs to update the install when clicked.

The reason you can't find setup.exe is because it isn't there. Once the files are installed, it isn't kept. The user isn't supposed to know where the files are, the system manages the location and updating of the app.

So, with all that, it appears you need a more normal install, not a ClickOnce. ClickOnce isn't intended to install services or other per machine files.

Comment: Thanks, so what about other solutions? I know of using Setup project in VS and a third party packager like Factory Setup..., Setup project is something interesting but not easy to master, and I see that many people are using third party packager than Setup project.